# Change color of blue outlines?

Tags: tinkercad

I am creating a model in TinkerCAD.  I don't want to 3D print it, I just want to create images of the perspectives.

I created a design, but all edges have blue outlines.  Here is a sample:
[image]

I would like the edges to be black.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with people on a TinkerCAD reddit forum, there is no way to eliminate the blue lines.

I moved to using blender instead and it is doing what I need it to.